# read and parse through csv file [python3.6]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am pretty new to python. I am trying to combine 2 csv files into one, selecting specific rows and columns.

csv1:

```
Host, Time Up, Time Down, Time Unreachable, Time Undetermined
server1.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
server2.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
```

csv2:

```
Host,Service, Time OK, Time Warning, Time Unknown, Time Critical, Time Undetermined
server1.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,server_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
server2.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,server_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
,application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000% (0.000%),0.000
```

Here is the code which combines the two files:

```
import csv
itertools as IT

filenames = ['csv1.csv', 'csv2.csv']
handles = [open(filename, 'rb') for filename in filenames]    
readers = [csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') for f in handles]

with  open('combined.csv', 'wb') as h:
    writer = csv.writer(h, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', )
    for rows in IT.izip_longest(*readers, fillvalue=['']*3):
        combined_row = []
        for row in rows:
            row = row[:3] # select the columns you want
            if len(row) == 3:
                combined_row.extend(row)
            else:
                combined.extend(['']*3)
        writer.writerow(combined_row)

for f in handles:
    f.close()
```

this combines and outputs this :

```
Host, Time Up, Time Down,Host,Service, Time OK
server1.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000%      (0.000%),server1.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%)
server2.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000%   (0.000%),,server_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%)
Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),,max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%)
,,,,application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%)
,,,,application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%)
,,,server2.test.com:1717,application_availability_check,100.000%   (100.000%)
,,,,server_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%)
,,,,max_hit_rate,100.000% (100.000%)
,,,,application_log_check,100.000% (100.000%)
,,,,application_sessions_check,100.000% (100.000%)
,,,Average,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%)
```

But here I want to extract only this following-
from csv1 & csv2 :

```
Host, Time Up, Time Down,Service, Time OK
server1.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000%   (0.000%),application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%)
server2.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000% (0.000%),application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%)
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: What are the criteria you're using to determine what rows (+ header) to extract?

Comment: i tried to fix the indetantion on your script but wasn't able to determine it 100%. Please check it and use 4 spaces as padding and not tabs. Specially important the `writer.writerow(combined_row)`. By the way, should the previous line be `combined_row.extend(['']*3)` instead of `combined.extend(['']*3)`?

Comment: @Adirio that seems to typo error while pasting the code here.

Comment: Thats what I thought, check it and edit your question

Comment: @PeterMularien Criteria is it must be in index if you see that in microdoft office excel 
values which i have mentioned comes at 1 cell (Host, Time Up, Time Down,Service, Time OK)
so i want to extract whatever is present in those colomns

Comment: @Adirio Edited the question regarding the indentation part rest is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv',skipfooter=1)
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv2.csv',skipfooter=1)


combined = pd.merge(df[['Host','Service','Time OK']],df2[['Host','Time Up','Time Down']], on='Host')

combined['Time OK'] = combined['Time OK'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
combined['Time Up'] = combined['Time Up'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
combined['Time Down'] = combined['Time Down'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])


combined.to_csv('combined.csv',index=False)
```

You should be able to solve this easily with Pandas, do you have that option available?

OUTPUT:

```
,Host, Time Up, Time Down,Service, Time OK
0,server1.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000%  (0.000%),application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%)
1,server2.test.com:1717,100.000% (100.000%),0.000%  (0.000%),application_availability_check,100.000% (100.000%)
```

Comment: It gives an error stating :  raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['Time OK'] not in index" -- but I have the following in index itself.

Comment: I have solved that as in my csv there is a space before ' Time OK' 
I am not able to get the required output asI have 0,1,2..as frist column, I dont want that can I delete that coloumn.
Also If I want to strip off the bracket part (100%) in coloumn 3 & coloumn 4 is that possible with pandas module ?

Comment: I have edited the solution and provided the output I see

Comment: See the changes I just made, does this get the expected output?

Comment: Works perfectly, just wnated to know regarding this line "combined['Time OK'] = combined['Time OK'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])" is it extracting the first row and application_availability check coloumn data?
if i wnt to extract 2nd coloumn data should i mention it as "combined['Time OK'] = combined['Time OK'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[1])?